# process.send is conditionally defined in Node.js

Tags: node.js

For whatever reason, in Node.js, the function process.send is defined in some environments but not defined in others. For instance, when I fork a child process from a parent process in Node.js like so:

```
//parent process
var cp = require('child_process');
var k = cp.fork('./child.js',['arg1','arg2','arg3']);
k.send('fail'); //k.send is defined...
process.send("ok, let's try this..."); //process.send is NOT defined
```

inside the child process:

```
//child.js
process.send('message');  //process.send is defined, and will send a message to the parent process above
```

The only way I know how to get around this is:

```
if (typeof process.send === 'function') { 
    process.send('what I want to send');
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `k.send('fail');` ?

Comment: If you mean something different than the question states, then please edit your question to correct it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Child processes have a `process.send` method to communicate back with the process that spawned them, while the root process doesn't have any "parent" to communicate, so its not there.  From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle):

> In the child the process object will have a send() method, and process will emit objects each time it receives a message on its channel.

To avoid having to "litter the code with conditionals", a temporary solution might be to just put a "noop" function in its place at the top of any "root" files you might be spawning processes from:

```
process.send = process.send || function () {};
```

Comment: this is super lame IMO. all processes should have a parent - process.send should do nothing if nobody is listening, just like every other pub/sub type API. but it's ok, we can just litter the code with conditionals, as I mention in the edit to the OP

Comment: Yeah there is likely a reason.  For now you could just put `process.send = process.send || function () {};` at the head of your 'root' file.

Comment: thanks Mr. McMillan, you seem to get it. Your solution looks like no worse then any others. This is a nasty one. I hope there is a really good reason for this...doubtful.

Comment: @AlexMills If you're "littering" your code with conditionals for this, something is probably wrong.  Parent/child processes typically share _very_ little code in a well-designed system.

Comment: first of all the OP still stands. second of all, the same code exists for testing and for not testing. that is the difference between the same code having process.send and not having process.send. work with me here.

Comment: @AlexMills Sure. `process.send` uses a JSON-over-IPC-fd mechanism, which is completely specific to node. It doesn't make sense to use that to try to send messages to a non-node process. So why not default it to a no-op? Because making a meaningfully-named method a no-op is disastrously undiscoverable and confusing. And you can easily turn it into a no-op yourself as this answer makes clear, whereas the opposite isn't really true (how would you determine that it's a no-op when its only effect is in another process?).

Comment: @AlexMills The form of IPC that node's `send` uses is via the parent opening an fd for the child and telling it which one to use via an env variable (`NODE_CHANNEL_FD`).  `process.send` will be available any time the parent process did this; not just when the parent process is a node proc.  Without this setup process, I'm curious what you expect `process.send` to do?  Despite your claim, there is no default IPC channel; the parent/child must cooperate to set one up.

Comment: @aaron, if you wanted process.send to do something instead of being a no-op you would start node.js with a flag. node index.js --ipc (or whatever). with that flag you would ipc set up with whatever OS level process started the node process.

Answer (score 1):

set a condition and call process.send in it
`if(process.send){ process.send() }`

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for Sapper & Svelte usage:

Basically, this error can be received in flow when you provided SAPPER_EXPORT variable in your environment.

More details about issue: https://github.com/Zimtir/SENT-template/issues/114