# TypeScript types by using Node multiprocessing are falsly assumed undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, multiprocessing, node-cluster

Using TypeScript to write a multiprocessing Node application I see the problem that e.g. this code is creating a compiler error although it's definitely working:

```
// main.ts
import * as child from 'child_process';
child.fork('my_fork.js', [], {});
```

```
// my_fork.ts
process.send({command: 42});  // Error: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
(<Required<typeof process>>process).send({command: 42}); // fine, but ugly
```

So how can I tell TypeScript that inside `my_fork.ts` the `process.send` will never be `undefined`?

Comment: `process.send?.({command: 42});`

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585540/process-send-is-conditionally-defined-in-node-js

Comment: Or just `process.send!(...)` if you're sure it's defined.